# Http PUT volley. Parameter in the middle of the url

Tags: android-volley, http-put, jsonobjectrequest

I am using Volley for my HTTP requests and I have an HTTP put URL which looks like below.
[http://mycompany.com/favorite/{roomNumber}/count](http://mycompany.com/favorite/%7BroomNumber%7D/count). I am using a JSON object request. How do I make the API work with the extra "/count" in the API? I am passing the parameter room number in the JSON object.

JSON Object request works fine with this type of URL "http://mycompany.com/favorite/{roomNumber}"

JSON Object request

```
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(METHOD_TYPE_PUT, url, jsonObjectParams, responseListener, errorListener)
```

Can somebody help me with passing the JSON object parameter in the middle of the URL

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try putting with help of your base URL like this? "http://mycompany.com/favorite/" + roomNumber + "/count" ? @Shravani

Comment: @Brahma Datta How can I change the JSONobject request below. My prameter is in the jsonObjectParams

JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(METHOD_TYPE_PUT, url, jsonObjectParams, responseListener, errorListener)

Comment: You want to add roomNumber dynamically to the Url right? @Shravani?

Comment: @BrahmaDatta Yes

Answer (score 0):

You can call the API dynamically like this,

```
private void getTheApiData(int roomNumber){

  JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(METHOD_TYPE_PUT, 
         "mycompany.com/favorite" + roomNumber + "/count", 
  jsonObjectParams, responseListener, errorListener)

}
```

and call the above API dynamically by the method when you get the new data every time like this.

```
getTheAPiData(20) //if room number is 20
```

let me know if you have any issue @Shravani